# Volume of cylindrical wedge, theta inquiry.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

Consider the following:

[image]

Can someone explain why the integration limits for $d \theta$ are between $\frac{3 \pi}{2}$ and $2\pi$?

Surely it should be between $\pi$ and $2\pi$??

Also why are the $r$ limits not between 0 and 4?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Suggestion: Sketch the relevant half-disk looking straight down on the $(x, y)$-plane, noting that the origin is at the left-hand end of the diameter, not at the center.

Comment: $-\pi /2<\theta <\pi /2$ describes the circle $r= 4 \cos  \theta $ going around once in the counterclockwise direction. $-\pi /2<\theta <0$ for the part in the fourth quadrant. So the integration limits should be from $-\pi /2$ to $0$ or from $3\pi /2$ to $2\pi $

Comment: Also why are the ranges of $r$ not between 0 and 4? Why is it between 0 and $4cos(\theta)$?

Comment: I edited my figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** (rather than an answer)

[image]

So the integration bounds with respect to $\theta$ are $\frac{3\pi}2$ and $2\pi$.

And at a given $\theta$: $0\le r\le 4\cos(\theta).$

Comment: Hey yeah that helps a lot for the $\theta$ limits. Do you by any chance know why the r limits are like they are? ie. why is it not between 0 and 4?

Comment: Also say that the cylinder was positioned at origin, if I am correct, this would mean the $theta$ limits are between $\pi$ and $2 \pi$ and the r limits between 0 and 2?

Comment: Yes. But the thing is shifted to the right by 2.